# Authenticating to Exchange through an ASP.NET Web API application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, exchangewebservices

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web API application with the goal of being able to retrieve emails from Exchange on behalf of users in our system.  Each user might belong to a completely different domain, so my application needs to be able to connect to multiple Exchange servers, some of which may be Office 365 while others might be on-premise (their premise, not ours).

Using the EWS Managed API, I've got the basic functionality working, but I'm unsure about the best way to handle the authentication for each user.  I've been reading through various MSDN articles about using EWS and the various authentication schemes, but much of it is still rather confusing to me.

The front end application that will be interacting with my application will have its own user datastore and authentication method.  Ideally, once a user has logged into that system, they will be able to get their emails from Exchange without having to provide their Exchange credentials each time.  It would be fine if they had to provide their credentials when the user first registers, but obviously I don't want to have to save their password in our system.  OAuth was sounding somewhat promising, but I don't have a good enough understanding of it at the moment to know whether it's what I should be pursuing.  Also, I've read that OAuth only works for Office 365 and not on-premise installations.

In short: What sort of mechanism should I be looking into that will allow an application to login to Exchange on behalf of a user through my application without having to provide their Exchange password each time?